# BackReference with Python Regular Expression with Unicode

Tags: python, regex, unicode, utf-8

I am on Google App Engine with Python 2.7 and here is the code snippet:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
KEYWORD = u"英語"
URL = u"http://www.google.com/"
content = u"和製英語（わせいえいご）とは、日本で作られた英語風の日本語語彙のことである。"
p=re.compile(u'('+ KEYWORD +u')(?!(([^<>]*?)>)|([^>]*?</a>))',re.UNICODE)
output=p.sub(u'<a href="'+ URL +'">\1</a>',content)
```

**The regular expression and p.sub worked correctly but the backreference `\1` wont work!** The output of `\1` is something like this: `ន`

I try to modify the code with `encode('utf-8')` but the result is the same:

```
p=re.compile(u'('+ KEYWORD +u')(?!(([^<>]*?)>)|([^>]*?</a>))'.encode('utf-8'),re.UNICODE)
output=p.sub(u'<a href="'+ URL +'">\1</a>'.encode('utf-8'),content.encode('utf-8'))
```

Can anyone told me what is wrong?

Comment: What is the unicode string for `content` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn the string with `\1` into a raw string by adding an `r` immediately before it:

```
output=p.sub(u'<a href="'+ URL +r'">\1</a>',content)
```

This prevents the 1 from being interpreted as a backreferenced 1. Proof:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
KEYWORD = u"英語"
URL = u"http://www.google.com/"
content = u"和製英語（わせいえいご）とは、日本で作られた英語風の日本語語彙のことである。"
p=re.compile(u'('+ KEYWORD +u')(?!(([^<>]*?)>)|([^>]*?</a>))',re.UNICODE)
print p.sub(u'<a href="'+ URL +'">\1</a>',content)
print p.sub(u'<a href="'+ URL +r'">\1</a>',content)
```

prints

```
和製<a href="http://www.google.com/"></a>（わせいえいご）とは、日本で作られた<a href="http://www.google.com/"></a>風の日本語語彙のことである。
和製<a href="http://www.google.com/">英語</a>（わせいえいご）とは、日本で作られた<a href="http://www.google.com/">英語</a>風の日本語語彙のことである。
```

Only the latter works (英語 is within the google link).

Comment: WOW! I spent hours and you solved it in seconds!!! Genius! I also add `r` in the first part of string: `p.sub(r'<a href="'+ URL +r'">\1</a>',content)`. and It still worked. I have one question: when a `r` string meets a unicode string, what will happen? The `r` string turn into unicode string? Thanks a lot?

Comment: You're very welcome. As for your followup: You mean when they're concatenated? It'll turn into a unicode string, but the backslashes will stay backslashes. For example: `u"a\t\t" + r"b\t\t"` gives `u'a\t\tb\\t\\t'` (notice the single backslashes for the first two \t's and the double backslashes for the next two)

Comment: More precisely: the `r` character changes how the string is input (in terms of how it treats backslashes), but not how it is actually stored (there's no difference between `"hello"` and `r"hello"`).